# Whatsapp media and Android 11: media folder changed?

Tags: updates, whatsapp-messenger, rsync

After upgrading my  OnePlus 6T from Android 9 to 11, all my images disappeared in WhatsApp, with typical error message:

> "Sorry, this media file doesn't exist on your internal storage"

The reason seems to be (see this [link](https://community.oneplus.com/thread/1506975)) due to the fact that the location of the media folder changed, from `WhatsApp/Media` at the first level to `Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media`.

So I am now trying to migrate this folder, by connecting my phone to my (Linux ) computer and using `rsync`: `rsync -avhz /path on computer/Internal\ shared\ storage/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp\ Images /path on computer/Internal\ shared\ storage/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp\ Images`.

However, I am facing a few issues:

- I am not sure which folder I should transfer? I see in particular some `.Links` folder, should I include it?
- Some files fail to be transferred with `rsync`, with message: `rsync: mkstemp "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OnePlus_OnePlus_11e47384/Internal shared storage/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/WhatsApp Images/.IMG-20200210-WA0124.jpg.8YamlC" failed: Operation not supported (95)`  what are those files?
- Lastly, I am not sure I am using the right parameters to `rsync` :-(

Thanks!

Comment: rsync over MTP is a bad idea. better enable developer options + adb and the open an `adb shell` on your PC. Inside the adb shell you can move files without transferring them over USB twice (first download then upload).

Comment: that makes sense, thanks @robert. Which `adb` command should I use? Is there one that allows a fine-tune sync as `rsync`, in particular copying/moving files without overwriting the target (as the new whatsapp folders got filled in in the meanwhile)? Thanks!

Comment: I am not an expert for all the Linux command arguments but keep in mind that Android only provides basic commands and often also the parameters supported by the binaries is reduced as they are provided e.g. by toybox.

Comment: thanks @Robert! I am still confused regarding the `adb` command you suggest to use? As it seems there is no `rsync`, I should use a combination of `cp` and `rm` to ensure that moving the files does not erase newer files on destination?

Comment: thanks @Robert! I am still confused regarding the `adb` command you suggest to use? As it seems there is no `rsync`, I should use a combination of `cp` and `rm` to ensure that moving the files does not erase newer files on destination?

Comment: With `adb shell` you are getting a shell on Android so you can make use of the Linux system below Android. The available commands are limited (early versions on Android didn't even had a `cp` command). What command are available or what parameters can be used is different from device to device and Android versions. I would check if `mv` knows the `-n` argument for "move if target does not exist".